# thunderbird cannot save sent mail locally

Tags: thunderbird

I am currently using thunderbird 102.13.0 (64-Bit) on kubuntu 22.04 and have several mail accounts there.

With one of them thunderbird refuses to save my mails locally after sending them. With another mail account it works. Both are using the same mail provider and the mail is sent, it is just not saved locally.

Disk space is no issue, since both accounts are on the same harddisk. Do you have any idea how I can save my  sent mails or ho to find out what the problem is without loosing all existing mails?

The error message is that it cannot save the mail "due to disk space". The error message is in German, so I won't copy it here, but that is the gist.